# How can I do itertools.product-controlled repetition of any character?

Tags: python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools, circular-permutations

This is  code with 8 repitios possible of all charaters

```
from itertools import *
for i in product(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'],repeat = 8):
    b = (''.join(i))
    print (b)
```

How can I do something like that - allow maximum  4 or 5 character repetition per 8-symbol string.  As an example, 222abbccc or a3333abd.

Allow every symbol from the list to repeat from 1 to 4 times at any place in 8-symbol string, but keep working permutation and try not lose performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function can implement additional rules above what `product` is producing.  Realize that 16 characters with a repeat of 8 has ~4 billion results without a rep limit.  The following function works but the example is limited for time:

```
from pprint import pprint

def generate(charset, length, maxrep):
    if length == 1:
        yield from charset
    else:
        for prefix in generate(charset, length - 1, maxrep):
            for char in charset:
                # Skip characters if the prefix already ends with the max rep
                if not prefix.endswith(char * maxrep):
                    yield prefix + char

pprint(list(generate('012',4,2)),compact=True)
```

Output:

```
['0010', '0011', '0012', '0020', '0021', '0022', '0100', '0101', '0102', '0110',
 '0112', '0120', '0121', '0122', '0200', '0201', '0202', '0210', '0211', '0212',
 '0220', '0221', '1001', '1002', '1010', '1011', '1012', '1020', '1021', '1022',
 '1100', '1101', '1102', '1120', '1121', '1122', '1200', '1201', '1202', '1210',
 '1211', '1212', '1220', '1221', '2001', '2002', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2020',
 '2021', '2022', '2100', '2101', '2102', '2110', '2112', '2120', '2121', '2122',
 '2200', '2201', '2202', '2210', '2211', '2212']
```

Comment: About 4 billion, i not need keep them  it be used at fly and given to another function...
so there more importand not lose geneation perfomance.

Comment: @tseries On my system generating the first 65536 entries for `generate('0123456789abcdef',8,4)` took 22ms, so it should be less than 65536 * 22ms or ~24 minutes to generate 4billion entries.  It should be somewhat faster given this algorithm skips entries with >4 symbols in a row.

Comment: there is one problems its not at fly how i undestand and it need list .

Comment: @tseries I didn't quite follow your question, but I think you want `for item in generate('012',4,2):` and don't store in list like my small example.  I called `list` to show the results in one big list.  You won't want that for billions of permutations.

Comment: for item in (generate('0123456789',8,4)):
    a = (''.join(item))
    print (a)
add to answer maybe some who be need to solution with no store it at list for they no search at commnets :)

Comment: @tseries Just 'print(item)`.  Function returns strings already.

Comment: 16,8,4 with non list 
Time:  1627.4064108
vs 
product with 16,  repeat=8 
Time:  1210.542135

slowe even than permutation with all 00000000 to FFFFFFFFF , so need think about another way :(

Comment: @tseries itertools is a built-in, so `product` is written in C using the Python C API, not straight python.

Comment: So how i undestand only way use product , but simple reject all what not need at next function.

Comment: In your timing, did you just product+join, or just product?  generate doesn't need join.

Comment: for i in product(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'],repeat = 8):
    b = (''.join(i))

Comment: @tseries I got product is 2x as fast, but anything I try to meet your criteria makes it slower than what I came up with so far.  Adding that comparison code slows it down again.

Comment: combinations_with_replacement , even faster that product  bit it not alow mirrored pairs :)
for i in combinations_with_replacement(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'], 8):
    b = (''.join(i))

Time:  0.09523279999999995

Comment: + if use as example 2 repeat at your script (generate('0123456789abcdef',8,2)):

00100e70 its not very try filter it )